# In Computer Science(especially in metalanguages using EBNF) , do the symbols -> and <- have specific meaning?

Tags: bnf, ebnf, metalanguage

My apologies if this is not in SO's domain - it's a bit high-level/theoretical.
I'm studying a custom Language Specification(called ACELandic if you interested). And it is based of of Extended Backus–Naur Form(EBNF ).

I see symbols like

```
<- 

->

<=

=>
```

that are really confusing me.
Are these standardized symbols? I recall stuff like this in Haskell, but I can't get my head around this..  I appreciate any tips or advice.

[image]

Comment: These aren't standardized symbols (it means dereference as a pointer in C/C++, and clearly something different here). Consult the documentation for the language you are working with to see what it means.

Comment: They mean different things in different languages. `=>` is usually used to denote values to a key in an array. `->` can be used to reference methods of an object (but usually a dot notation is used)